# Transforming a RDD by flattening the values of the tuple

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm trying my best to understand the map-reduce functionality in Apache Spark, and I'm stuck at flattening (not sure if this is the correct term) the RDD.

I have the following RDD structure in scala:

```
RDD[Tuple2[Long, Tuple2[String, Array[String]]]]
```

An example of this would be something like:

```
(1, ("a", ["alice", "bob"]))
(2, ("b", ["charlie", "dave"]))
(3, ("a", ["edward"]))
```

I would like to transform this RDD to be of the following type:

```
RDD[Tuple2[Long, Tuple2[String, String]]]
```

looking like:

```
(1, ("a", "alice"))
(1, ("a", "bob"))
(2, ("b", "charlie"))
(2, ("b", "dave"))
(3, ("a", "edward"))
```

Unfortunately, I can't get my head around this manipulation via the map/flatMap functions.
Is this type of transformation even possible, and if so, how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Using flatMap might be one possible approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is perfectly possible:

```
rdd.flatMap { case (k, (x, ys)) => ys.map(y => (k, (x, y))) }
```

Comment: ah ok! So I can use the Scala 'map' function from the Array inside the 'flatMap' function of the RDD. Thanks for the tip!